# How to understand the behavior of back to back operators?

Tags: c, logical-operators, operator-precedence

I'm having confusion using AND and OR though this is basic question I'm having lot of confusion. I understand there is short circuit methodology when AND and OR logical operators are being used.

```
Assume int a,x=0,y=0;
a). a= 10 && ++x && y++ 

Values a=0,x =1,y=1 [expected ]


 b). a= 10 && ++x || y++
 Values a=1 ,x=1,y=0 [short circuit 
  ,expected ]

 c). a= 10 || ++x || y++
 Values a=1 , x=0, y=0 [short 
  circuit ]
```

My questions are :

1. a = 10 && y++

   ```
   Values a =0, x=0(default didn't 
   change ), y=1 [ expected no short 
   circuit y is incremented later and 
   hence a =0 ]
   ```
2. With reference to question 1.

   ```
   a = 10 || ++x && y++
   ```

Actual values :

```
 a=1, x=0,y=0
```

What I expected :

```
 a = 0, x=0, y=1
```

Explanation: 10 || ++x (short circuit )

So I remain with a = (1 && y++) => a=0 (no short circuit , and y has post increment) hence a =0,y=1.

How can I understand my question 2; I believe I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `||` and `&&` force left-to-right evaluation.  `&&` has higher precedence than `||`<sup>1</sup>, so `a || b && c`is parsed as `a || (b && c)`.  Remember that with `a || b`, if `a` is non-zero, then the result of the expression is 1 regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` is not evaluated at all.  So in the expression `a || (b && c)`, if `a` is non-zero, then `(b && c)` is not evaluated.

So, given `a = 10 || x++ && ++y`, `10` is non-zero, meaning the result of the expression will be 1 regardless of the result of `x++ && ++y`, so neither `x++` nor `++y` are evaluated.

---

1. Precedence *only* controls how expressions are parsed (which operators are grouped with which operands) - it *does not* control the order in which expressions are evaluated.